# Applying user selected texture to cube dynamically?

Tags: three.js, textures, raycasting

I’m creating a cube using BoxGeometry and trying to apply the texture that the user has selected.

I created a raycaster and use that raycaster inside mouse down event.
If the object is present on cursor position then a user-selected texture gets applied.

So far everything works fine. Then I added if-else condition if the user selected single image for texture then that single image gets applied whole body of cube means all side of cube gets that image as material.

But if the user selected more than one image suppose three images then only three sides of cube get material. This also works very well.

Now a real problem when user select only three images remaining side of cube remain black and that is okay only material applied side shows up.

Now if user again select a single image and click on cube to apply single image texture to whole body again ray caster gives problem that
“–can’t access property “side”, the material is undefined–”
so this callback function which i added to select image files

```js
function onUserMultiImageSelect(event) {
     materialArray.length = 0;
     length = multiFilesId.files.length;
   
     let multiImage = [];
     let userMultiImageUrl = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      
        multiImage[i] = multiFilesId.files.item(i);
        userMultiImageUrl[i] = URL.createObjectURL(multiImage[i]);
        materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(userMultiImageUrl[i]),side:THREE.DoubleSide }));

    }
    isTextureSelect = true;
}
```

this is callback funtion which gets called when i click on object to apply texture

```js
function onMouseButtonDown(event) {
    var rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
    var mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;
    let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    let pointer = new THREE.Vector2();

    pointer.set((mouseX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(mouseY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1);

    raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera);

    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {

        var curentIntersectedObject = intersects[0];

        if (isTextureSelect) {     
            if(length == 1){
                var singleImage = multiFilesId.files.item(0);
                var singleImageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(singleImage);
                var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(singleImageUrl);
                curentIntersectedObject.object.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
             }else{
                 curentIntersectedObject.object.material = materialArray;

             }
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for taking the tour. Your question would really benefit from sharing some code, specifically where you perform the raycasting, and where you apply the textures. If you can create a minimal example that reproduces the problem, that would be best.

Comment: @TheJim01 thank you for your reply and sorry for late response on my own post

Comment: @TheJim01 can you please check now I've added the code

Comment: When selecting new images, are you ever clearing `materialArray`? Continuing to push materials into the array might cause unknown results.

Comment: @TheJim01 yes clearing the materialArray